# How to manipulate variable in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: sed, jenkins-pipeline

been trying several trial and errors on where or how to cut the string in the variable and assign to a new variable to be used by jenkins stage. Normally just removing **-TEST** Jenkins pipeline indicated below:

```
properties([
    [$class: 'RebuildSettings', autoRebuild: false, rebuildDisabled: false], 
    parameters([choice(choices: ['SQA-ENV-CLONE', 'DEV-ENV-CLONE'], 
                description: 'Select the ENV', name: 'ENV')])])

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {

    stage('VALIDATE ENVIRONMENT') {
      def ACTIVE = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo $ENV | sed -e 's/-CLONE//g'")

      steps {
         echo 'Checking 1st the ${ACTIVE}'
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

Error I'm getting

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 6: Not a valid stage section definition: "def ACTIVE = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo $ENV | sed -e 's/-CLONE//g'")". Some extra configuration is required. @ line 6, column 9.
       stage('VALIDATE ENVIRONMENT') {
       ^

1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:330)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Lets say I choose "DEV-ENV-CLONE" as the value I'm expecting to have a successful build with this output:

```
Checking 1st the DEV-ENV
```

Comment: It is not clear at all, could you please do mention what is the expected output in your post in code tags and let us know then?

Comment: Oh I missed to add that, thnaks for checking @RavinderSingh13 Lets say I choose "DEV-ENV-CLONE" as the value I'm expecting to have a successful build with this output----> Checking 1st the DEV-ENV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need move the `def ACTIVE = sh(...)` into pipeline step [script](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script), They are Groovy script, only can be wrapped by `script` step.

```
stage('VALIDATE ENVIRONMENT') {

  steps {

    script {
      ACTIVE = sh(
        returnStdout: true, 
        script: "echo $ENV | sed -e 's/-CLONE//g'"
      ).trim()      
    }

    echo "Checking 1st the ${ACTIVE}"
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi yong,Jenkins job was success however it didn't give the expected result. This is what I got from the logs = "Checking 1st the ${ACTIVE}"

Comment: Sorry, we should use double quote for `"Checking 1st the ${ACTIVE}"` . More detail see http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation

Comment: Hi yong, it gives me an error from logs = groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ACTIVE for class: WorkflowScript

Comment: I removed the `def` ,please try again.